# How to read data into a time_t variable using scanf()?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings

This code gives me warnings:

```
$ cat test.c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

int main() {

    time_t t;
    scanf("%lld", &t);
    printf("%lld\n", t);
    return 0;
}
$ gcc test.c -o test
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:7: warning: format ‘%lld’ expects type ‘long long int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘time_t *’
test.c:8: warning: format ‘%lld’ expects type ‘long long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘time_t’
$
```

Apart from the warnings, the code works as expected.

What should I do to not get the warnings on compilation (no compiler pragma tricks please)?

Comment: I'd stick in a printf() to see what sizeof(time_t) is and then cast it.  Usually uint32_t works for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The exact type of `time_t` depends on your platform and OS. It's still quite often 32 bit (either `int` or `long`), not 64, and some even use floats. The correct thing to do is to read into a known-size integer (either `int` or `long long`) and then assign the value to a `time_t` as a second step.

Comment: I would use the largest possible size to be safe. And `strtoull` would be a better choice than `scanf`.

Comment: @R..: `strtoll()` since `time_t` is generally signed.

Comment: +1. Indeed, POSIX permits `time_t` to be an integer or real floating type.

Comment: Indeed. `strtold` might be the best choice.

Answer (score 3):

You need the format to match the time_t definition of your system. Compile with

```
gcc test.c -o test --save-temps
```

then

```
grep time_t test.i|grep typedef
```

Most likely, this will tell you that time_t is "long int", so you need to scan it with "%ld".

Comment: And if you get different answers on different architectures you can `ifdef` your code to make it 'portable' to them

Answer (score 2):

First, your compiler is right: nothing guarantees that [time_t](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_t) is actually a 64-bit signed integer. It could be a 32-bit integer or even a floating-point value, depending on the platform.

Now, if you're *absolutely*, *positively* sure that `time_t` is a `long long` on your platform, and you want to avoid the formatting warnings, you can do:

```
time_t t;
scanf("%lld", (long long *) &t);
printf("%lld\n", (long long) t);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a known size of integer with [`scanf()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) and then convert the result to `time_t`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    long long llv;
    time_t t;
    scanf("%lld", &llv);
    t = llv;
    printf("%lld\n", (long long)t);
    return 0;
}
```

In this example, it doesn't seem to buy you much, but if you wanted to pass the variable `t` to some of the time-manipulation functions, then you would have the correct type to work with.

If you look at the linked URL for (the POSIX extended version of) `scanf()`, you'll see that there is no mention of `time_t` type there.  Thus, any mechanism to read `time_t` values with `scanf()` has to be somewhat less than straight-forward.  Ditto, anything that prints `time_t` values is also somewhat less than straight-forward.