# convert a long number to date , time in C

Tags: c, time.h

i am solving spoj problem
where current time stamp is sqaured and then divided by 400000007 and the remainder is converted into a dat time
below is the technique i used..

```
remainder = result%4000000007 ; 

printf("%ul\n",remainder); 


//convert the timestamp into date , time 

dt = localtime(&remainder); 
// use any strftime format spec here 
// strftime(b, sizeof(b), "%m%d%H%M%y", dt); 
// fprintf(stdout, "%s", b); 
// printf("%s\n",asctime(localtime(&remainder))); 
 ltime = (time_t)remainder; 
 printf("%s\n",asctime(dt)); 
 printf("%s\n",ctime(&ltime));
```

Error shown is Segmentation fault , at `asctime` , also `ltime` is time_t variable ,'b' is a buffer ,  `dt` is struct tm * , and also i have tried to convert the remainder into `time_t` variable , but still dint work . Also , Commented code shows my attempts .
Using debugger , i found asctime returns null .

where is the problem ?

Comment: Is remainder and result at least a long long (64-bit int)?  Also, any compiler warnings with /wAll enabled?

Comment: yes , they are unsigned long long

Comment: @MichaelDorgan : but i am not sure if they are 64-bit

Comment: Doesn't seem to crash (see: http://ideone.com/YWTsAV). Show more code?

Comment: remainder is unsigned long long

Comment: @CodeJack: Then you would have gotten a warning passing it into `localtime`. Get rid of all the warnings, then see if it still crashes. Show the code without the warnings.

Comment: You were right @user315052 , i cleared the warnings , the problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say exactly what is wrong from the code presented. However, in your comments, you related that `remainder` has the type `unsigned long long`. However, you pass its address to `localtime()`, which is an error. `localtime()` expects a `time_t *`.

What might have happened is that due to the wrong type being passed in, `localtime()` detected some error and returned a `NULL` value. Then, passing this value into `asctime()` resulted in a `NULL` return value as well.

As an aside, your `printf` has the wrong specifier. Use `%llu` to print an `unsigned long long`.

Comment: Yep, hence my /wall suggestion.  Warnings really do matter :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan , @user315052 : if the timestamp is to be given by user , then we need to convert the string input into type `time_t` , so can i use `strtoull` for that purpose ?? I mean , how to scanf the input directly into a `time_t` variable ??

Comment: @CodeJack: You could, or you can assign `remainder` to an `time_t` variable. You already do that with `ltime`.

Comment: the statement `scanf("%llu",ltime);` would do ??

Comment: @CodeJack: No, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171478/how-to-read-data-into-a-time-t-variable-using-scanf